# L-functions and Hecke theory for general number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

I often read about analytic number theory on $\mathbf{Q}$ when it turns to explicit computations, so I wonder how much results generalize as they stand and the use of $\mathbf{Q}$ is merely made for ease of notations. Let $F$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal and $\mathfrak{n}$ denotes generically an integer ideal.

Does the decomposition of $L$-functions in Euler product still holds:
$$L(s, f) = \sum_{\mathfrak{n}} \frac{c_\pi(\mathfrak{n})}{N(\mathfrak{n})^s} = \prod_\mathfrak{p} \prod_{j=1}^n (1-\alpha_j(\mathfrak{p})N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s})^{-1} \quad ?$$

And does the Hecke theory and Hecke operators works as well, giving the coefficients $c_\pi(\mathfrak{n})$ up to normalization, etc. with for instance
$$T_\mathfrak{p} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\mathfrak{p} & \\ & 1
\end{array}
\right) \quad ?$$

Is there a reference for these general notations?

Comment: See Iwasawa-Tate for $GL(1)$, and Jacquet-Langlands (et al) for $GL(2)$...

Comment: There are more readable references than Jacquet-Langlands, e.g., Gelbart's book, Bump's book and some articles in "An introduction to the Langlands program."  I also like Cogdell's notes.